# Google FormApp.openByUrl() Exception: No item with the given ID could be found

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Here is the situation, I am trying to basically clone a Google Classroom. It works fine for the most part except for copying Google Forms. Since the Classroom API cannot add a Forms object, I have to use links to the Forms, which is fine. However, when the links are simply copied to the new Classroom it just points to the existing Form with all the old responses. So I am trying to make a copy of the Form using the URL in the link, but I get the error "Exception: No item with the given ID could be found. Possibly because you have not edited this item or you do not have permission to access it."
I am the owner of the Classroom, the Form, and the script. I can put the URL into the browser and get to the Form.
I am pulling the link from the Classroom using Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.list() then using JSON.stringify() on the materials so I can hold them in a Spreadsheet cell. When the time comes to copy the Form, I use JSON.parse() on the string so I can drill down to the link and get the url.

```
const x = JSON.parse(materialsString) 
if(Object.keys(x).includes('link'){
  const url = x.link.url
  const form = FormApp.openByUrl(url)
}
```

The url looks like https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/GOOGLEFORMID/viewform . I have also tried to use just the id from the url and get the same error. I have also tried the DriveApp with the id and get "Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFileById on object DriveApp."
Is it even possible to get a Form this way? I have used FormApp.openByUrl() before with SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getFormUrl() in the past with success.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem here is that `FormApp.openByUrl` excepts you to pass the url to the editable version of the form (something like `https://docs.google.com/forms/d/FORM_ID/edit`). The link to the live version of the form is just view only and the form IDs in the 2 urls are not the same,  which is likely why extracting the ID from the URL is not working for you (assuming that's what you were doing).

I'm not very familiar with the Google Classroom API, but checking out the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/Material), it looks like the `Materials` object you are parsing must be one of the following types: `Link`, `Form`, `YoutubeVideo`, `SharedDriveFile`. Not sure if you are able to force the file to be of one of the other types (perhaps based on how you are uploading the files to Google Classroom), but the `SharedDriveFile` type does have an `ID` field that you would theoretically be able to use with `DriveApp.getFileById`.

Alternatively, similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69479212/13771937) and assuming all the forms exist on your Google Drive as well, you can build a dictionary of all the forms on your drive that maps the EditUrl to the PublishedUrl (`FormApp.openByUrl("EDIT_URL").getPublishedUrl()`), which you can then use to clone your forms. I haven't tested this, but likely something like this would work for you:

```
function getFormsDictionary() {
  var forms = DriveApp.getFolderById('{ YOUR FOLDER HERE }') // if the forms are not all under one folder, you can just do DriveApp.getFilesByType
    .getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_FORMS);
  var formsDictionary = {};
  while (forms.hasNext()) {
    var form = forms.next();
    var file = FormApp.openByUrl(form.getUrl());
    var editUrl = file.getEditUrl();
    var publishedUrl = file.getPublishedUrl();
    
    formsDictionary[publishedUrl] = editUrl;
  }
  return formsDictionary;
}
```

Then when you are parsing your materials:

```
const formsDictionary = getFormsDictionary();
const x = JSON.parse(materialsString) 
if(Object.keys(x).includes('link'){
  const url = x.link.url
  const editUrl = formsDictionary[url];
  const form = FormApp.openByUrl(editUrl);
  // do more things here
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately the forms do not always exist on my Google Drive, so it would be difficult make the dict for all the Forms. So far my workaround is to access the teacher folder on Drive and get access to the Forms from there. It is a more tedious process since I have to connect the Form to the correct assignment, although now I am thinking that I could then grab the published URL from the Form in the Drive and match it to the link from the Materials. Hmm.....